# How to delete files inside hidden folder with python?

Tags: python

I want do delete a file, for ex. 'myfile.txt' that is stored under a hidden folder. Is it possible to do this in python?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you researched this question thouroughly, and not found an answer online?

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden folder"?  Different filesystems implement such a thing in different ways, usually that depends on the operating system, which you do not specify.

Comment: If you can't see it then it doesn't exists!

Comment: @AttilaBognár: that depends on how you are looking

Comment: My file is in AppData in another folder created by an app. So i'm on windows. For me what i've found so far did not worked.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just have the path included the hidden folder as follows:

UNIX:

```
path = "desktop/.hidden_folder/myfile.txt"
```

WINDOWS (Code from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-remove-hidden-files-and-folders-using-Python)):

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
  import win32api, win32con
def file_is_hidden(p):
  if os.name== 'nt':
    attribute = win32api.GetFileAttributes(p)
    return attribute & (win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
else:
    return p.startswith('.') #linux-osx
[os.remove(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if file_is_hidden(f)]
```

Then deal with the file as you wish.