# Deleting hidden directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory where there can be `.unwanted` directories anywhere within the directory tree. I want these deleted.

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('.unwanted', onerror=True)
```

This does not work because the directories are hidden. Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 374, in _rmtree_unsafe
    with os.scandir(path) as scandir_it:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '.unwanted'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/SYSTEM/CODING/PYTHON/import.py", line 31, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree('.unwanted', onerror=True)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 516, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 377, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.scandir, path, sys.exc_info())
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Nevermind the line numbers, the sample code is from a larger script.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-remove-hidden-files-and-folders-using-Python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817308/how-to-delete-files-inside-hidden-folder-with-python

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the correct directory? Better use absolute path.

Comment: working dir is `e:\import` but the `.unwanted` directories are located somewhere within, inside unknown directories.

Comment: Then you have to use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20walk#os.walk), [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) will not magically remove all subdirectories beneath your working dir

Comment: Are you sure that `.unwanted` is the name of your hidden file. I consider using `.` as the first character in the file name makes it a hidden file in linux, but its not the same case in windows. The pull path that you have provided looks like a FS in windows.

Comment: Yes the dir name is indeed `.unwanted`, and yes, in Windows. Not sure how but they are indeed hidden, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import os
os.system("rm -rf .directory_name")
```

Comment: `'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: This is a Linux command, use a Windows command instead.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I tried `os.system("for /d /r %u in (.unwanted) do rd /s /q %u")` but I get a lot of errors `the system cannot find the file/path specified)`, and the `.unwanted` directories remain. It has to delete them within the whole tree.

Answer (score 0):

Your call from onerror seems wrong? Maybe you wanted write the following?

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('.unwanted', ignore_errors=True)
```

The param 'onerror' specify an handler.

From the documentation: If onerror is provided, it must be a callable that accepts three parameters: function, path, and excinfo.

See the official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Comment: This also only deletes the one directly within root

Answer (score 0):

The solution found in the link provided by @OcasoProtal works with little modification, although some of it is still a mystery. Comments welcomed.

```
import shutil
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for d in subdirs:
        if d == ".unwanted":
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d))
```

Comment: `root` is the current path that you get from os.walk, so you can not drop it. os.walk returns a 3-tuple, you might not need everything from that tuple, but it's not good to remove it. Just add a print statement and you will see ;)

Comment: so I can change `for root, subdirs, files in os...` to `for subdirs in os...` since the `.unwanted` dirs cannot be in the root, and cannot be files. ..?

Comment: Nope, you can't. But I suspect that you can drop the `for ... subdirs` loop. Unfortunately I currently have no python at hand to test it. Just do a `for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):` with a print of all three elements afterwards and you will see how os.walk works (or use a debugger to step through the code and inspect the variables)

Comment: I also have to delete `*.parts` that are in the root only, I'm sure this can be added to the code above without the need for separate code..? Do I only need another `if` statement in the end? It doesn't list files though..

Comment: Yes, another if should be sufficient, even if only in root. But you need [os.remove](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove), because rmtree only works on directories. Don't forget to `import os`. As I said: If you are unsure just add a print instead of the rmtree/os.remove

Comment: How do I avoid the exception when a `.parts` file is in use?

Comment: You are a [help-vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)! Use [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) and please do the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)